# Passing date table to range function in Kusto

Tags: mysql, database, date, azure-data-explorer, kql

In Kusto Query Language, is it possible to pass a column of dates to range? I am trying to render a timeline chart mapping table4 values along those dates. `todatetime("1598149365")` will work but not table_dates3. Or if there is some similar way of doing this.

```
TableName
| where Name == "abc"
| project table_dates1, table_dates2, table_dates3, table4
| make-series num=count() default=0 on todatetime(table_dates1) in range(todatetime(table_dates2), todatetime(table_dates3), 1h) by table4
| render timechart
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "[from start] [to end] step step" syntax instead of the old range() syntax. The "from" and "to" are optional, if not supplied they will be the min/max times for each time series. So maybe something like:

```
TableName
| where Name == "abc"
| project table_dates1, table_dates2, table_dates3, table4
| make-series num=count() on todatetime(table_dates1) step 1h by table4
| render timechart
```

Comment: Thanks Adi. It works, but I was hoping to limit the output within a range of dates, a start and end date.

Comment: `| make-series num=count() default=0 on todatetime(table_dates1) in range(todatetime("1598165365"), todatetime(t"1598149365""), 1h) by table4`
does exactly what I need but I need the values to be the table of dates instead of literal dates. The first column is accepted in the `on` but not in the range. Is there a way to do that?